# Is there a good apt syntax for installing an approximate package version?

Tags: apt, versions, syntax

Sometimes I don't immediately know the full package version details, but I do know which major.minor version I'm after-
For example, say I have package `foo-package` with several versions of debs available in my repository, and I want to get `1.4.1~build1` while `1.5.1~build3` is also available

If I knew the complete version, I could install it as

```shell
apt install foo-package=1.4.1~build1
```

Is there a convenient syntax to only give `1.4` to fetch the lower package?

Comment: Note for future readers: This is a corner case; an advanced use of apt. Most users never need to specify versions. Apt will happily figure out compatible versions for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this has nearly the same syntax as Gentoo, where I might use

```shell
emerge -aqv1 "=bar-baz/foo-package-1.4.*"
```

```shell
apt install foo-package='1.4.*'
```

Note this is only practical for testing as the package will be updated to the latest version it can be with the next `apt upgrade` unless pinned!